# SwiftUI Text width animation

Tags: animation, text

expected result

[image: 1]

current result

[image: 2]

I want to make it animation controllable

Open - text shows with animation
Close - text hide with animation

My code:

```swift
struct HomeView: View {
    @State var isOpen = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Appearing title text")
                    .frame(width: isOpen ? 200 : 0, height: 20, alignment: .leading)
                    .animation(.linear(duration: 2))
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                HStack {
                    Button("Open") {
                        isOpen = true
                    }
                    Button("Close") {
                        isOpen = false
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .padding(.top, 100)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Prompt me, please, how can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried making the 200 an `@State`? Then you can use a slider

Comment: Yes, I tried **@State var width = 200**, but closing animation is still wrong. 
Slider is not suitable for my logic

Comment: So you want us to guess what you have tried? What works and what doesn't work.

Comment: I have tried many variants, but none work